# Prove a density result in the usual Hilbert triple

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

While studying the Hilbert triple, I've found the usual warning with identifications of dual spaces.

Let $V \subset H$, two Hilbert spaces with $V$ dense in $H$ and continuously embedded in $H$. The inner product in $H$ is denoted with $(\cdot, \cdot)_H$, the one on $V$ with $(\cdot, \cdot)_V$.  By Riesz representation theorem, we can identify $H$ with its dual $H^{\star}$. I've been asked to prove that:

> $H$ is dense in $V^{\star}$

Here's my attempt:

I conside a functional $T \in V^{\star}$. By Riesz, we know there's a $w \in V$ s.t. $$T(v)=(v,w)_V$$ for every $v \in V$.

Now, I pick a sequence $\{w_k \} \in V$ such that $w_k \rightarrow w$.

Then, I consider the functional $T_{w_k}:H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $T_{w_k}(u) = (w_k,u)_H$, which is an element of $H^{\star}$ by Schwarz inequality, as $H$ is Hilbert.

Now I consider the $$||T - T_{w_k}||_{V^{\star}}$$ and I want to show this goes to $0$. By definition of dual norm, and given a $v \in V$: $$(T-T_{w_k})(v)=(w-w_k,v)_V \rightarrow 0$$ as $w_k \rightarrow w$.

So I've found that given a functional $T \in V^{\star}$, I can find a sequence of functionals $T_k \in H^{\star}$ s.t. $$||T-T_k||_{V^{\star}} \rightarrow_k 0$$

$\square$

Is that correct?

Comment: What is the "usual Hilbert triple" ,

Comment: @JeanMarie The one defined in this question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251857/a-few-questions-about-the-hilbert-triple-gelfand-triple?rq=1). Basically, we have $V \subset H$ with $V$ dense in $H$ with continuous inclusion

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: you're welcome! Do you think my argument is correct?@JeanMarie

Comment: Sorry but it's not my domain of expertise...

Comment: No problem :-) @JeanMarie

Comment: Shouldn't $T-T_{w_k}$ have one term which is an $H$ inner product and one term that is a $V$ inner product?

Comment: @podiki I'm sorry but I don't see why, could you be more precise?

Comment: Your definition of $T$ is a $V$ inner product and your definition of $T_{w_k}$ is an $H$ inner product. But when you calculate $T-T_{w_k}$ it's just a $V$ inner product.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, the solution is sadly incorrect.

One major mistake is in the step
$$
(T-T_{w_k})(v) = (w-w_k,v)_V,
$$
which is not true because you have defined
$T_{w_k}(u) = (w_k,u)_H$ and not $T_{w_k}(u) = (w_k,u)_V$
(the latter would not allow you to show $T_{w_k}\in H^*$).

Note that there is no equality in any sense between $(\cdot,\cdot)_H$
$(\cdot,\cdot)_V$ (only continuity estimates for the induced norms).

**Comments on your approach**:
I do not think your approach is likely to succeed.
You start by picking a sequence $w_k\in V$ with $w_k\to w$.
There, you might as well choose the constant sequence $w_k=w$.
So, in this approach, there is nothing to be gained by considering
the sequence $w_k$ (compared to considering just $w$).

A proof of the density is not so simple in my opinion, and some theory can be quite useful.
An idea for a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332495/).